# How to return observable from service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular2-observables

My service code prints the observable in console but how to return back the observable to component

service code:

```
const visit$ =  this.db.object('visitordetails/'+$key);
this.item = visit$.subscribe((result) => console.log(result)) as Object;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your component to use the observable, you have to return it from the service and subscribe to it in the component:

**service.ts**

```
get() {
  return this.db.object('visitordetails/'+$key); 
}
```

**component.ts**

```
item: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.get().subscribe(item => {
    console.log(item);
  });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>{{item}}</div>
OR
<div>{{item.property}}</div>
```

Comment: yes now i get the values in component in the console. Please share how cani bind it UI as an model

Comment: I added some HTML to my answer. Depending on the structure of item, you'll be able to display it as it is or you might have to display its properties.

Comment: thanks a lot i would like to post few more  questons to you

Comment: 1) Could you pleae tell how to filter the data by date in firebase
 so that i can make use of it in FirebaseObservableListObejct?

Comment: This is outside the scope of this question unless you edit the OP. You can accept this as the answer and create a new question (preferred) or edit your first post with the firebase code.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't subscribe within the service.

```
return this.db.object('visitordetails/'+$key)
```